# Class static attribute value shared between requests

Tags: python, django, apache, python-2.7, mod-wsgi

I have a a static class attribute that gets modified in the same http request.

```
class A:
  x = {}

  def fun(k,v):
    A.x[k] = v
```

My issue is that when your do another http request, the last value of the previous request persists.

Am using Django through Apache's mod WSGI .

How can I make the static value persists in the same request but not to another request?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Inspired by muddyfish's answer I implemented a middleware's process_response

```
import A

class ClearStaticMiddleware(object):
  def process_response(self, request, response):
    A.x = {}
    return response
```

Thank you all for your responses.

Comment: If you don't use `threading.local`, the value of `A.x` will be shared with all concurrent requests (and could be cleared at any point by one of them completing and reaching your middleware).

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of static variables is for them to persist in the class rather than the instances used to handle a particular request. This is dangerous when using threader or event-based servers as the static variable will be shared not only with the next request but also with all requests handled in parallel.

I assume class `A` here is a class-based view. In that case, you can change your attribute to be an instance one instead:

```
class A(…):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super()
        self.x = {}

    def foo(k, v):
        self.x[k] = v
```

As class-based views are re-instantiated for each request they serve, the value will not bleed into other requests.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but this not my need, I need a variable that is shared between all class instances but only for the current request

Comment: In that case I suggest using a `threading.local` and resetting it using middleware. Be aware however that by introducing global state you are making your application so much harder to test.

Comment: Oussama> It is very, very rare that such a thing is needed. Usually, if you reach that point, then it means you have a problem in how your code is organized. You should fix that, not try to work around it.

Answer (score -1):

At the end of each request, clear the cache

```
@app.teardown_request
def teardown(exc):
    A.x = {}
```

Comment: This is new for me, does this goes in the view? or in the class ? thank you for your quick answer

Comment: It don't believe it matters where it goes, but I believe it would be best to go somewhere in a global scope. - I think the decorator registers the function with flask so it doesn't need to be anywhere. (I am guessing)

Comment: Thank you, I never used Flask before I will look into it, seems interesting

Comment: Am sorry but this seems not the answer for me, am using Django and it seems that flask is an alternative web framework for Django and not a Django module as I first thought.